# BLE Manufacture Advertise data

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

In BLE manufacturer data, while converting from bytes to String, I am getting data like this:

JLG BLE

> ÿS7452396��������ÿSPH90234380,100084,������������������.

Even converting from bytes to hex then hex to string printing like this only.

hex format :

> 02010608084A4C4720424C45020A0A0FFF530704373435323339360000000015FF5307504839303233343338302C3130303038342C000000000000000000.

In ios Manufacture data printing like this

1.Raw Data(Ascii):

> 53070355 52323031 39313130 33315048 39303233 34333830 2c313030
>   3038342c

2.String Value:

> SUR201911031PH90234380,100084,

So in Android, how can I print raw data and string value like iOS

I am getting scan result like this

> ScanResult{device=D6:23:72:02:69:72, scanRecord=ScanRecord
>   [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=null,
>   mManufacturerSpecificData={1875=[80, 72, 57, 48, 50, 51, 52, 51, 56,
>   48, 44, 49, 48, 48, 48, 56, 52, 44]}, mServiceData={},
>   mTxPowerLevel=10, mDeviceName=JLG BLE], rssi=-59,
>   timestampNanos=34872779608333, eventType=27, primaryPhy=1,
>   secondaryPhy=0, advertisingSid=255, txPower=127,
>   periodicAdvertisingInterval=0}

```
private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        try {

            BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
            String name = btDevice.getName();
          //  Log.d("advertisedData",);
            if (name != null && name.equalsIgnoreCase(JLGConstants.BLE_NAME)) {
                JLGBluetoothManufacturerData bluetoothManufacturerData = new JLGBluetoothManufacturerData();
                bluetoothManufacturerData.setBluetoothDevice(result.getDevice());
                bluetoothManufacturerData.setRssi(result.getRssi());
                Log.e("address",""+result);


                if (bluetoothManufactureDataList.isEmpty()) {
                    String scanHex = "";

                    SparseArray<byte[]> advertisedData = result.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData();
                    ScanRecord advertisedDataBytes = result.getScanRecord();

                    Log.d("advertisedData hex format",JLGCommonFunctions.bytesToHex(advertisedDataBytes.getBytes()));

                   Log.d("advertisedData  String format",JLGCommonFunctions.bytesToString(advertisedDataBytes.getBytes()));


                } 

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JLGCommonFunctions.logExceptions(e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        /*do nothing*/
    }
    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        /*do nothing*/
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following bytes are in the raw data received both on Android and iOS:

> 39303233343338302C3130303038342C

Before this part, your JLG peripheral encodes different manufacturer data between Android and iOS.

Presumably, the iOS data include the private BLE address of the peripheral, because with iOS it is not possible to get the private address of an advertising BLE peripheral via the advertising packets using CoreBluetooth.

If it is necessary for your app to uniquely identify an unknown BLE peripheral, this identifying information must be supplied by the peripheral, as long as this information fits in an advertising packet.

Comment: why getting like this kind of question marks  JLG BLE ÿS7452396��������ÿSPH90234380,100084,������������������

Comment: This is not related to your JLG manufacturer. The question marks are placeholders for null or empty value.

Comment: � are replacement for unknown characters in the set.